# GPS coordinates of android device are not getting

Tags: android, gps

I am working in android.
i want to get GPS coordinates of my android device.

I am using this code to get my coordinates:-

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 


Location location = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(location!=null) {
               myLongitude = location.getLongitude();
               myLatitude= location.getLatitude();
            }
            else {
               myLongitude =0;
               myLatitude= 0;
            }

           LocationListener mlocListener;
           mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
           mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

and this the class:-

```
 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
 {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

    {
        myLatitude= loc.getLatitude();
        myLongitude=loc.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

but all the time i get latitude and longitude to zero only. please suggest me what mistake i have done.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655

Comment: you want co-ordinate using Network provider in device or in emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```